# Unable to use variables in files that are included from other files

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I'm using SASS and I have the following file structure:

```
resources/
    style.scss
    partials/
        _variables.scss
        _components.scss
components/
    componentA/
        componentA.scss
```

- style.scss includes _variables.scss and _components.scss.
- Variables are defined in _variabels.scss
- SASS files located in the components directory are included from _components.scss

Unfortunately, if I create a variable in _variables.scss it's not accessible to any of the component sass files (eg, componentA.scss). It complains that the variable isn't defined. Is this a limitation of SASS? Do I need to define some sort of global scope or something?

Comment: Are all of your includes being included in `style.scss`?  Can you add your include declarations to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You must import `_variables.scss` before using any variable.

By the example given, the error comes from the `componentA.scss` that is compiled to a separate css file to `css/components/componentA/componentA.css` so when the stylesheet is compiled it has no variables defined because `componentA.scss` doesn't import the `_variables.scss`